# CSS rule to select an element which doesn't contain an element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of elements that look like..

```
<div id="hi">
    <div class="head">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

..except some of them don't have the footer element, only a head. I want to give elements without a footer a bottom border. I'm hoping for something like..

```css
#hi:hasno(.footer) {
    border-bottom: 1px black dotted;
}
```

Is there a CSS selector I could use for this, or should I just use a JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select elements that contain no other elements using the `:empty` selector, but what you need won't be available until CSS Selectors Level 4’s [`:has`](https://caniuse.com/css-has) and [`:not(selector list)`](https://caniuse.com/css-not-sel-list) are both implemented in browsers. So no, it can't be done in pure CSS. Now whether or not you should use a JavaScript equivalent depends on what you really want to achieve here. If it's a minor detail, feel free to add it with JavaScript if it's not too much of a problem. If it's a huge, essential feature, consider restructuring so you don't need this kind of selector.

Comment: Obligatory jQuery propaganda `$('#hi:not(:has(.footer))')`

Comment: The answer was given in 2012. It is now 2022. A decade has come and gone. `:not()` has kind of arrived but `:has()` has not. jQuery propaganda has become even more irrelevant than it was back then. Has some new, CSS-only, way of achieving `.hi:has(.head)` emerged?

Comment: @Sixtyfive: `:has` is supported in current Chrome, and in Firefox behind a flag. Apart from that, no.

Comment: Firefox just (2023-12) added the support of `:has()`, https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the situation with your background, you could put the border on `#hi` permanently, and then overlap that with your `footer` by giving the `footer` either `margin-bottom: -1px` or `position: relative; bottom: -1px;` and hiding the border when the footer is present.